# Joining 3 SchemaRDDs

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm doing a three-way join with three SchemaRDDs (each on the order of a million records, stored in Parquet files on HDFS).

The schema is as follows:

- table1 has four fields: id, group_id, t2_id and a date
- table2 has three fields: id, group_id and t3_id
- table3 has three fields: id, group_id and date

I'm trying to figure out the relationships between table1 and table3 within a group.

The SQL Query I'd use would be:

```
SELECT group_id, t1.id, t3.id 
  FROM table1, table2, table3 
  WHERE t1.group_id = t2.group_id and t1.t2_id = t2.id and 
    and t2.group_id = t3.group_id and t2.t3_id = t3.id and
    t3.date < t1.date
```

However, I'm trying to do it in Spark:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.{Inner, JoinType}


val tab1 = sqlContext.parquetFile("warehouse/tab1_pq")
val tab2 = sqlContext.parquetFile("warehouse/tab2_pq")
val tab3 = sqlContext.parquetFile("warehouse/tab3_pq")

val relationship = tab1.as('t1).
  join(tab2.as('t2), Inner, Some(("t2.group_id".attr === "t1.group_id".attr) &&  ("t2.id".attr === "t1.t2_id".attr))).
  join(tab3.as('t3), Inner, Some(("t3.group_id".attr === "t2.group_id".attr) &&  ("t3.id".attr === "t2.t3_id".attr))).
  where("t3.date".attr <= "t1.date".attr).
  select("t1.group_id".attr, "t1.id".attr, "t3.id".attr)
```

So this seems to work -- however it runs significantly slower than impala on the same (3 unit, EMR) cluster.  Is this the right way to do it?  Is there a way to make this more performant?

Thanks for any help